# DOS work-around for the "&" character?

Tags: string, command-line, batch-file, dos

DOS doesn't seem to deal well with the "&" character in  a string. I'm trying to parse url's, many of which have one or more &'s. If I do something like:

```
    set var = "http://finance.yahoo.com/mbview/threadview/?v=m&bn=2"
    echo %var%
    pause
```

I get

> ECHO is off.
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Removing the & character rectifies this, which would be a suitable work-around,  but I need to do this in code. Is there any help for this?

Comment: How about single quoting the URL instead ?

Comment: Are you really using `DOS` or are you talking about the commandline in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the ampersand when you use delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=http://finance.yahoo.com/mbview/threadview/?v=m&bn=2"
Echo !var!
```

Comment: +1, You beat me this time :-) I was trying to write a full explanation.

Comment: that worked. very nice. Thought I was sunk.

Comment: However,

while this line works right:

 echo !str! > my.txt

this one loses everything after the '&', including the '&':

 echo !str! | clip

Comment: `echo !str! > my.txt` works, but `echo !str! | clip` fails, as pipes create a new cmd.exe context, so the line is parsed twice. For more you should open a new question

Comment: Oh -- so you gave me a solution that only works once! LOL Seems like this is similar to the byval/byref scenariio.

Comment: No, my solution works. You didn't ask about pipes, in batch this makes a huge difference

Comment: didn't mean to sound ungrateful. May take a look at one of these interpreters under the hood. regards.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Windows Command line that must be what you are looking for.

```
set "var=http://finance.yahoo.com/mbview/threadview/?v=m^&bn=2"
echo %var%
pause
```

watch **^&** in code

Comment: That worked, too. Nice! Command Prompt language is gnarly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `var` and `=`:

```
set var="http://finance.yahoo.com/mbview/threadview/?v=m&bn=2"
echo %var%
pause
```

Comment: actually, I only typed it wrong in the question box -- actual code was typed as you have it. Thanx.